# Cannot `gulp install`, results in `Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined`

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, npm, gulp, nvm

I have installed NVM and NPM to an EC2 instance using [this guide from AWS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-up-node-on-ec2-instance.html).

I then install gulp and gulp-cli

> npm install --global gulp
>
> npm install --global gulp-cli

Then navigate to my project and run

> gulp i

And I get this error

> /home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.5/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:129
>       gulpInst.start.apply(gulpInst, toRun);
>                     ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
>       at /home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.5/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:129:19
>       at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
>       at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:443:11)
>       at startup (node.js:139:18)
>       at node.js:968:3

`node -v` returns v4.4.5

`npm -v` returns 2.15.5

`gulp -v` returns

> [13:22:47] CLI version 3.9.1
>
> [13:22:47] Local version 4.0.0-alpha.2

I am now stuck and unsure how to get `gulp i` to run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means that `gulpInst.start` is `undefined`.

It's impossible to say anything specific without seeing your particular configuration but here are some issues on GitHub related to that:

- https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp-cli/issues/84
- https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp-cli/issues/31
- https://github.com/pattern-lab/edition-node-gulp/issues/61
- https://github.com/pattern-lab/edition-node-gulp/issues/66

Hopefully it will help you get started.

Comment: It seems that running `npm install -g gulp-cli` resolved the issue, despite me running it multiple times before :/

Answer (score 11):

All over the internet, the proposed solution is to run `npm install -g gulp-cli`. At first, this didn't work for me, but after **closing and opening a new console**, it worked.